# Solve the following problem, $u'(t)+p(t)u(t)=0,\;\;u(0)=0,$ $p(t)=\begin{cases}2& 0\leq t< 1,\\1 &t\geq 1\end{cases}.$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, laplace-transform

Using Laplace transform, solve the following problem.

$$u'(t)+p(t)u(t)=0,\;\;u(0)=0,$$
$$p(t)=\begin{cases}2& 0\leq t< 1,\\1 &t\geq 1\end{cases}.$$

Here's what I've done:

Taking the Laplace transform of both sides
$$L(u'(t))+L(p(t)u(t))=0,$$
$$sU(s)-u(0)+L(p(t)u(t))=0,$$
$$sU(s)+L(p(t)u(t))=0.$$

I'm stuck at this point. Please, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0< t< 1$, we have $u'(t)+2u(t)=0$, $u(0)=0$ for which there is trivial  solution $u(t)=0$.

For $t\ge 1$, we have $u'(t)+u(t)=0$ for which the solution is $u(t)=Ae^{-t}$ where $A$ is arbitrary constant.

**Added**: As per David's comments, using the continuity of $u(t)$ at $t=1$ we get $A=0$. Hence the solution will be $u(t)=0$ for $t\ge 0$

Comment: But $u(t)$ is one function, not two separate functions.  So the first part gives $u(1)=0$ which is an initial condition for the second part.  And this gives $A=0$.  So your solution is: $u(t)=0$ for all $t\ge0$.

Comment: @David...Is it necessary that $u$ is continuous at $t=1$ as there are actually two ODE's defined in different domain.

Comment: I would not say there are two DEs, but this is probably a matter of terminology so I won't argue.  However it seems clear that the OP is asking about one function.  The DE is given for all $t\ge0$ so we need a solution which is defined and differentiable, therefore also continuous, for all $t\ge0$.

Comment: @David...I took account of the possibility that $u(t)$ may be piecewise continuous for $t\ge 0$.

Comment: Well in that case the given DE is not satisfied at $t=1$.

Comment: I think the point which is stopping me is to believe that it is just one DE.

Comment: @David...I have made an edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0\dfrac{d u(t)}{u(t)}=\int_0-p(t)\ dt=\begin{cases}2t& 0\leq t\leq 1,\\t &t\geq 1\end{cases}.$$
then $$u(t)=\begin{cases}0& t\leq 0,\\e^{2t}& 0\leq t\leq 1,\\e^t &t\geq 1\end{cases}.$$

Comment: I guess it should be $e^{-2t}$ and $e^{-t}$

Comment: yes they are. thanks.

Comment: Please, can you teach me how to take inverse Laplace to get the results?

Comment: Please, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884434/laplace-inverse-of-s2us-0-and-s1us-0

Comment: I didn't use laplace method.