# Laplace inverse of $(s+2)U(s)=0$ and $(s+1)U(s)=0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I asked this question here and I was given an answer but with some steps unfolded [Solve the following problem, $u'(t)+p(t)u(t)=0,\;\;u(0)=0,$ $p(t)=\begin{cases}2& 0\leq t< 1,\\1 &t\geq 1\end{cases}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884318/solve-the-following-problem-utptut-0-u0-0-pt-begincases2/2884374#2884374).

My question now is, how do I take the La

Taking the Laplace transform of both sides
$$L(u'(t))+L(p(t)u(t))=0,$$
$$sU(s)-u(0)+L(p(t)u(t))=0,$$
For $0\leq t<1$
$$sU(s)+2U(s)=0,$$
$$(s+2)U(s)=0.$$

For $t\geq 1$
$$sU(s)+U(s)=0,$$
$$(s+1)U(s)=0.$$

Can someone show me how to take the Laplace inverse of this to get $u(t)=e^{-2t}$ and $u(t)=e^{-t}.$

Comment: No. Write the function $p$ using step functions.

Answer (score 2):

First for $0 \le t \le 1$

$$
sU(s)+2U(s)=u(0)\Rightarrow u(t) = u(0) e^{-2t}(\phi(t)-\phi(t-1))
$$

and with $u(1) = u(0)e^{-2}$ we proceed solving for $1 \le t $

$$
sU(s)+U(s) = u(1)\Rightarrow u(t) = u(1)e^{-(t-1)}\phi(t-1)
$$

finally

$$
u(t) = u(0) e^{-2t}(\phi(t)-\phi(t-1))+u(0)e^{-2}e^{-(t-1)}\phi(t-1)
$$

or

$$
u(t) = u(0)\left(e^{-2t}(\phi(t)-\phi(t-1))+e^{-t-1}\phi(t-1)\right)
$$

Here $\phi(t)$ is the Heavside unit step function.

Comment: but $u(0)=0 $  so the solution is null ..and $u(1)=0$ because of $u(0)$ but also the step function $\phi(1)-\phi (0)=1-1=0$

Comment: @Isham The problem as formulated has as solution $u(t) = 0$ because any homogeneous DE with  null initial conditions has null solution. I wrote the exact response to initial conditions. If the system were submitted to a step function, then the formulation should be non-homogeneous as $u'(t)+p(t)u(t) = \phi(t)$ with $\phi(t)$ the Heavside unit step function.

Comment: I do agree, the problem is really weird ...and I think it has no solution..

Comment: @Isham  As long as $u(0) = 0$ the solution is $u(t) = 0$.

Comment: +1 Cesareo for your answer  another question : shouldnt it be here $e^{-t}$ $$sU(s)+U(s) = u(1)\Rightarrow u(t) = u(1)e^{-(t-1)}\phi(t-1)$$

Comment: @Isham Remember that the time origin now is at $t = 1$ so the response is translated now.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer...I got it now

Comment: @Isham you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Correct your formulas with step function: 
$$(s+2)U(s)=\dfrac1s$$
and
$$(s+1)U(s)=\dfrac1s$$